# ADXL345 acceleration data readout looks strange - STM8

Tags: sensor, spi, stm8

after finally finding out how to create a software SPI connection i now can successfully read the data from an ADXL345 acceleration sensor. But they look rather strange to me, this are some sample values:

`X: -252 Y: -532 Z: 9616`

These values are measured in +-16g mode with full precision (so basically we have 4mg/LSB). These values are in mG (e.g a value of 1000 would represent 1G). I don't quite understand why the Z-value is so high?

I initialize the ADXL345 with this code:

```
write_command = ((0x00 | 0x31) << 8) | 0b01001011;//set SPI 3wire & 16g range & full-res
write_command = ((0x00 | 0x2D) << 8) | 0x08; //Enable measurements
```

I send the values over uart to an UART / USB converter. The values are changing if i start to move the sensor board so i think my reading part is correct:

```
//read X-Axis
x0 = readRegister(0x80 | 0x32);
x1 = readRegister(0x80 | 0x33);

//read Y-Axis
y0 = readRegister(0x80 | 0x34);
y1 = readRegister(0x80 | 0x35);

//read Z-Axis
z0 = readRegister(0x80 | 0x36);
z1 = readRegister(0x80 | 0x37);

//convert in milli-G [4.0mg/LSB] in +/- 16g mode @ full-res
x = ((x1 << 8) | x0);
y = ((y1 << 8) | y0);
z = ((z1 << 8) | z0);

*x_val = x * 4;
*y_val = y * 4;
*z_val = z * 4;
```

Do you have any ideas what i do wrong at the data processing part?

Comment: It seems a reading in m/s^2... verify that the registers got the correct configuration.

Comment: What do you mean? Which registers?

Comment: You did show only the evaluation of the `write_command`. You should have called something like `writeRegister(write_command)` to issue that command. Then you could, eventually, read the value of the register with x0 = `a=readRegister(0x80 | 0x31);` and see if it agrees with the value you wrote.

Comment: We need to know the format of the numbers being read in, especially byte order.  Be careful about the endianness of your variables.

Comment: Post your entire code. For example, is your example printout the raw value "z" or the scaled value "z_val?"  We can't tell.  Also, be careful with your units - you mention "1000 would be 1g," but that is 1000 mg is 1g, 1g would be represented by 250 LSB (1000mg / 4) as the raw readout from the ADXL345.  Also, check your datatypes.  If z0 and z1 are uint8_t types (since your reads will always return 8 bits), you will lose all z1 data in your (z1 << 8) | z0 conversion and you'll need to typecast first.  Lastly, check axis orientation.  Your X printout looks suspiciously like 1g on its side.  :)

Comment: I, of course, also write these values to the register, i just didn't show the function call. Reading works fine because i can read the DEVID-register and i get the correct value back.

@ScottSeidman How can i show you the number or the byte order? I don't know how the controller read its value?

This is my entire code: http://pastebin.com/TZRdQi3N

Answer (score 2):

Putting my original comment into an answer now that you've pasted your code here.

1. My suspicion was right that you are losing your upper byte by shifting them away, because you've declared z0/z1 as a uint8_t.  So (z0 << 8) always turns into 0x00.  Make these uint16_t instead.
2. I think your communication is probably OK, like you mentioned, but one way to test it for sure is to check the WHO_AM_I register.  Most devices have something like this (might name it differently).  The ADXL345 WHO_AM_I register is at 0x00 and it's hardcoded to 0xE5 (or 345 octal, yuk yuk, clever Analog Devices engineers).  First thing your enableADXL() function should do is check this register and look for the hard-coded answer as expected.  If it doesn't match, your communications channel is broken so no point continuing.
3. Since it appears you are printing out x, y, and z (not x_val, y_val, and z_val), 1g will be about 250 LSB, so again double-check that your device isn't on its side because your X-axis value is -252.

But I think #1 will fix you.

Comment: Ha! I didn't notice the 345 octal :)

Comment: Oh, and the OP is printing x_val, y_val, and z_val, but has used local (to main.c) x, y, and z variable names in his call to the readXYZ() function.

Comment: As I said in a comment before i can read the DEVID successfully. And i use `x,y,z` as parameters for the function `readXYZ`. So basically the function stores the `x/y/z` axis values in the parameters i call it with.

Comment: Good call, I missed that but see it now.  So how did it go trying my first suggestion of making all the xyz/01 variables as uint16_t?  The problem is still that your shift occurs *before* the assignment to "z," so z1 data is already lost by the time you OR in z0.

Comment: I changed my code to this: http://pastebin.com/DLSDKvbc but it is still not working. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: @binaryBigInt  Whoops, I said make these uint16_t but since the ADXL345 returns signed values, make these int16_t instead.  That would seriously mess with the values.  Let me know if that still doesn't work, everything else in your code looks fine.  I'll edit my answer for posterity.

Comment: @binaryBigInt Wait, my brain is not working today.  The final 16-bit result is a twos complement number but since you are treating these more as strings that you're pasting together, keep as uint16_t.

Comment: @binaryBigInt You might be doing something wrong with your ltoa() function.  Normally I'm used to this having 3 arguments, not 4, and the third being the radix of the result.  For decimal you should be using "10" (2 for binary, 16 for hex), not "1."

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer,
the third parameter of the `lota`function is used to describe how many of the characters in the fourth parameter are in front of the actual number. So if i type `10` there will be 10 `0` to fill up.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your implicit conversions might be messing you up.  This is from the code in your link:

```
    uint8_t x0 = 0;
    uint8_t x1 = 0;

    int16_t x = 0;

    //read X-Axis
    x0 = readRegister(0x80 | 0x32);
    x1 = readRegister(0x80 | 0x33);

    //convert in milli-G [4.0mg/LSB] in +/- 16g mode @ full-res
    x = ((x1 << 8) | x0);

    *x_val = x * 4;
```

Since x1 is an uint8_t, the `(x1 << 8)` statement shifts all the bits away, leaving only zeros.  Instead, try this typecast:

```
    x = (((uint16_t)(x1) << 8) | x0);
```

Or, you could just declare x1 as a uint16_t.

Similarly, depending on your compiler, you may need to explicitly typecast the uint16_t value to a int16_t value when assigning it to x.  Altogether, this would look like:

```
`x = (int16_t)(((uint16_t)(x1) << 8) | x0);`
```

Comment: I changed the datatype from `x1`, `y1` and `z1` to `uint16_t` but that didn't help. Also casting the value to `int16_t` didn't change anything :(

Comment: @bismack Any ideas what i could do to fix the wrong number problem?